# having really hard time with qsort()

Tags: c

i've been trying to sort 2D array with qsort like:

I want to sort it with qsort increasing or decreasing by x value, and if x values are same, i want it to compare the y values. it should be printing like this:

1, 2 - 2, 3 - 2, 4

I tried so hard, please help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct testt{
    int start;
    int len;
};

int comparePlease(const void* p, const void* q)
{
    struct testt* x = (struct testt*)p;
    struct testt* y = (struct testt*)q;

    return *x - *y;
}

int main()
{

    struct testt test[5] = {        {40, 20},
                                    {50, 30},
                                    {30, 100},
                                    {50, 35},
                                    {25, 15} };

    qsort(test, sizeof(test) / sizeof(test[0]), sizeof(int), comparePlease);

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eArc2.png)

Comment: Where is the code that cals `qsort`? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: i have added it @Jabberwocky

Comment: `sizeof(int)` -> `sizeof(struct test)`

Comment: @Jabberwocky or `sizeof(test[0])`

Comment: @MikeCAT i added the error image on post, can u please check it?

Comment: @Jabberwocky it gives errori incompleted type is not allowed. on visual studio

Comment: @Vabregas `struct test` is not declared in the right place, show a [mcve] and don't post pictures of text, post text as text.

Comment: @Jabberwocky i add my entire code now. please help me

Comment: Look very closely at `struct testt` and at `struct test`

Comment: Sigh: and why do you use the `x` and `y` members instead of `len` and `start` members?

Comment: uh, the image of the error messages doesn't match the code you posted!?!

Comment: @Jabberwocky thank you so much man! thank you so much! now i need to debug and learn what this comparator doing. thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many issues:

- use  `struct test` everywhere and not `struct testt`.
- `qsort(test, sizeof(test) / sizeof(test[0]), sizeof(int), comparePlease)` should be `qsort(test, sizeof(test) / sizeof(test[0]), sizeof(test[0]), comparePlease)`
- the struct members are `x` and `y` instead of `start` and `len`.
- your `comparePlease` function  was totally bogous, you cannot naively substract structs, it doesn't make any sense. What would `{40,20} - {30,40}` be?

You want this:

```
struct test {
  int x;
  int y;
};

int comparePlease(const void* p, const void* q)
{
  struct test* lhs = (struct test*)p;  // left hand side
  struct test* rhs = (struct test*)q;  // right hand side

  /* if x values are same */
  if (lhs->x == rhs->x) {
    /* compare the y values */
    return lhs->y < rhs->y ? -1 : lhs->y > rhs->y;
  }
  else {
    /* compare the x values */
    return lhs->x < rhs->x ? -1 : 1;
  }
}

int main()
{

  struct test test[5] = { {40, 20},
                                  {50, 30},
                                  {30, 100},
                                  {50, 35},
                                  {25, 15} };

  qsort(test, sizeof(test) / sizeof(test[0]), sizeof(test[0]), comparePlease);
}
```

`comparePlease` is a quick and dirty fix, there is possibly room form improvement, but it should give you an idea.

Comment: Could you please be consistent in how you return values?